# vim macro to convert CamelCase to lowercase_with_underscores

Tags: vim, macros

Is there a vim macro to convert CamelCase to lowercase_with_underscores and vice versa?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tim Pope’s [`abolish.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1545) can convert among `camelCase`, `MixedCase` (also known as `PascalCase`), `snake_case`, and `UPPER_CASE`, as well as convert (one-way) to `dash-case`.

Position the cursor on any of `fooBar`, `FooBar`, `foo_bar`, or `FOO_BAR` and use

- `crc` to convert to `fooBar`
- `crm` to convert to `FooBar`
- `cr_` or
  `crs` to convert to `foo_bar`
- `cru` to convert to `FOO_BAR`
- `cr-` to convert to `foo-bar`

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: Tim Pope is awesome. So many great plugins.

Answer (score 6):

[Yes there is](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/CamelCase_to_under_lined_and_vice_versa), and as a bonus there's one there to go the opposite direction as well!

Quote from the wiki in case it goes away:

```
" Change selected text from NameLikeThis to name_like_this.
vnoremap ,u :s/\<\@!\([A-Z]\)/\_\l\1/g<CR>gul
```

and for the opposite direction:

```
" Change selected text from name_like_this to NameLikeThis.
vnoremap ,c :s/_\([a-z]\)/\u\1/g<CR>gUl
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's almost perfect, except on my vim, it doesn't change the first letter of the CamelCase name.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: Very nice.  I did find I needed to make this change for the snake to camel direction: `vnoremap tos :s/\C\(\U\&\S\)\([A-Z]\)/\1_\l\2/g<CR>
`

Answer (score 1):

[lh-dev](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev) also provides commands to convert between naming styles:

```
:NameConvert snake
```

will convert the word under the cursor to snake_case.

```
:%ConvertNames/\<m_\k\+(/getter/gc
```

will convert each occurrence of the pattern to a getter name, assuming the user confirms the transformation (`:h :s_flags`)

The styles supported are of two kinds:

- exact styles (snake_case, UpperCamelCase, lowerCamelCase)
- semantic styles (local, global, member, parameter, getter, setter, constant, static, function, type, ...) which can be [tuned to fit current project naming conventions](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/after/template/vim/internals/vim-rc-local-cpp-style.template).

Answer (score 1):

I created a command like this:

```
command! Ctl
    \ exec "norm \"xygn" |
    \ let @y = substitute(@x, "\\([^A-Z]\\)\\([A-Z]\\)", "\\1_\\2", "g") |
    \ let @y = tolower(@y) |
    \ exec "norm cgn\<C-r>y" |
    \ let @@ = ":Ctl\n"
```

You first must search for a string you want to replace `/nameToReplace` and then you run `:Ctl`, and the next search match will become `name_to_replace`. The command puts itself into the `@@` register so you can repeat the action by pressing `@@`.